# Conditional formatting does not work for filling ranges of cells with colors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do a simple conditional formatting (Excel 2013) for some rages of cells in the sheet:
Fill the even rows with white color and the odd rows with gray

Condition: If any cells after I6 including I6 (cells belong to the column I) are not equal empty apply the fill to the $I$7: to $O$999

the process:

Conditional formatting tab -> New rule -> use a formula to determine which cells to format

For the odd rows the formula =and($I6<>"" mod(Row(),2)=1) white color and apply it to the the range: $I$7:$O999

for the even rows the formula =and($I6<>"" mod(Row(),2)=0) white color and apply it to the the range: $I$7:$O999

But I keep getting nothing, and when I returns to the conditional formatting rules manager I see that some quotes signs (") has been added to the formula.

What is the problem?

[image]

and sometimes I get this message

[image]

Comment: Probably, you're pasting the formula with (or letting) an space at the beginning.

Comment: You should try Mario Javier Eugenio Estrada's answer, but with `$I6` instead of his `I7`, meaning `=AND($I6<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=1)`. In your text-formula the second `and` is wrong and in the screenshot there are too many`"` and `=`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have put a space before the `=`, making Excel think that it is a string, rather than a formula.

Your image shows:

```
Formula: =" =AND($I6<>"""",MOD(Row(),2)=0)"
```

When it *should* say:

```
Formula: =AND($I6<>"",MOD(Row(),2)=0)
```

If you are applying it to the range $I$7:$O999, you probably also want to change the $I6 to match ($I7).

Answer (score 0):

You should put this formulas:

For odd rows: =AND(I7<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=1)

For even rows: =AND(I7<>"",MOD(ROW(),2)=0)

Comment: Sorry, But I updated the questions fro better understanding

Comment: The problem is solved when I replaced the comma with semicolon. Does this have anything to do with the version of Microsoft excel knowing that I am using 2013 version

Comment: No. it is to do with your regional settings of the computer, not your Excel version. Your default separator must be set to `:` instead of `,`.